# How can I deserialize a specific JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I am trying to serialize what I think is an unusual JSON structure in a .NET Core 2.2 app.

```
{
    "id": "002a40a1-2e31-4663-a8d0-a4e6e2742d62",
    "data": [
        1,
        [
            "value",
            false
        ]
    ]
}
```

My confusion comes in when trying to model the data property in c#

```
public class DataItem {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    string id;

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public object[] data;
}
```

I do not know how to properly model this structure in C# to allow Newtonsoft to deserialize it.

Comment: use properties instead of fields

Answer (score 1):

since it does not have structured format, I suggest you to use `dynamic`. or If you use `object[]` you can manually iterate over each object and check object types within if condition.

Alternatively you can use `IDictionary<string, JToken>`

```
public class DataItem {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    string id;

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the `JsonExtensionDataAttribute` if you don't know what the data is at runtime.

So it will abstract your 'data' into a Dictionary of JToken's

```
public class DataItem {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    string id;

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> data;
}
```

You can see more details here: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-jsonextensiondata-with-jsonnet/ and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm